# How to launch this particular script from any desktop at any location?

Tags: windows-7, script, cmd.exe, vbscript, exec

This part seems to be the code to modify:

```
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("c:\TEST")
```

How can I change that so that it works on any computer from any location/path?

Would I need to integrate an additional code that allows the person

to temporarily type in their computer name - i.e. JOHN-PC / MARY-PC / PAUL-PC

Does it need to call out a specific location/path or is there a way to remove it altogether?

---

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

' create the filesystem object
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' get current folder
Set fol = fso.GetFolder("c:\TEST")

' go thru each files in the folder
For Each fil In fol.Files
' check if the file name contains underscore
If InStr(1, fil.Name, "john") <> 0 Then
    ' replace underscore with space
    sName = Replace(fil.Name, "john", "dave")
    ' rename the file
    fil.Name = sName
End If
Next

' echo the job is completed
WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

Comment: What folder do you want it to run on? You could provide the folder as an argument? Or have it run in the current folder the script is in?

Comment: desktop or downloads, the issue seems to be that it will not be able to distinguish from admin to admin if i send the file to a friend and he wants to execute from the desktop or downloads folder. the last one i suppose. thnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of options.

1. You could base the file path from `%USERPROFILE%` - for example, `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\`. This will give you the Download folder for the current logged in user.
2. You could provide it as an `argument`, more info on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b05k8s(v=vs.84).aspx).

Effectively you would then call the file with `cscript FILE.vbs "C:\Temp\Folder\"`, and in your script use:

```
objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(objArgs(0))
```

3. The example you have found would give you the current working folder. For example, if your VBS is in `C:\Temp\Test\test.vbs`

   `Set fol = fso.GetFolder(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("."))`

This would make `fol` the folder contents of `C:\Temp\Test` - Bear in mind, this would include your VBS file you're running..!

Comment: For 3. were would I need to add this line? How would the script look after the fact?

Comment: Updated my answer, just swap out the line as it is.

Comment: Saw that last edit, it seems to work. Thank You!

Comment: @ClaudiaL. No problem. As said, be careful as this will be catching the VBS file also. If you can mark the answer as accepted if it has helped you (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)